# How to sort gridview to show by specific column the row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I've tried for so many times to find a way to sort my gridview but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Table Columns:

```
Name | Age | Old device name
============================
John | 22  | KRT 20
Jon  | 21  | KSR 12
Jco  | 22  |
```

I would like to know how can I make a drop list , to choose in the gridview to sort all the rows by Old device name , so I should see in the gridview only the rows that contains the old device name.

I'm using a SqlDataSource and GridView in ASP.NET.

Comment: You can set the column name in sortExpression property of SqlDataSource, and call DataBind() method, it will order your gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've updated the code based on your comments.

One way to do this is to set your DropDownList to `AutoPostBack="true"`, and handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  In this example, the items in your DropDownList should match the column names of your GridView.  I've used "ColumnA", "ColumnB", and "ColumnC"

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="myDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>ColumnA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ColumnB</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ColumnC</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then, in code behind, you can <strike>set the "SortExpression" of your `GridView` and databind it</strike> just call the sort function based on your dropw down's selected value:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView1.Sort(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, SortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

You could replace the `SortDirection.Ascending` with `SortDirection.Descending`.

*Note: This answer assumes that the values in your drop down are the names of columns / fields in your datasource.*

Comment: I get porperty or indexer System.Web.Ui.WebControls.GridView.SortExpression cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @InziIrina Ah, it's been a while since I did that.  I've updated the code (and this time, I tested it on my machine - so you should be good!).

Comment: do I need to choose a data source the columns?or just add the items with text of the columns?

Comment: I'm talking about the dropdown , I don't know the way to configure it

Comment: @InziIrina Correct, you would add `<ListItem>` elements with the names of your columns.  I added that into the example.

Comment: Okay I did that , and nothing happened to the girdview

Comment: Huh , it worked but..not :( , I mean I choose to order by a Column , it should show in the data grid all the rows that have values in that column , and it shows me just the column selected with no values in it .

Comment: @InziIrina If you are sorting "Ascending", it would show empty rows first.  That is how string sorting works.

Comment: yeyyy it worked , thank you very much :* , also I would like to know while sorting , how can I sort them in order? for example : i have 5 rows , only row 1 and 4 has values , and If I order by the column , it shows me the value from 4 then from 1 , can I get from 1 then from 4?in order

Comment: To sort in the other order, just change the second parameter of the call to the `Sort` function from `SortDirection.Ascending` to `SortDirection.Descending`.  I mentioned that in my answer =)

Comment: noh, I mean while sorting the gridview by a column values the sorting of the rows that have values in that column to be ascending.